# Menu nav li active remove

Tags: javascript, html

I want to assign "active" class to the menu. The active clip is throwing but not deleting. I do not understand why you did not delete. Thank you in advance to those who can help.
There is no error, it surprises me that it does not delete this way

```
<ul id="avia-menu" class="menu av-main-nav">
    <li id="menu-item" class="menu-item">
        <a href="home">
            <span class="avia-bullet"></span>
            <span class="avia-menu-text">Home</span>
            <span class="avia-menu-fx">
                <span class="avia-arrow-wrap">
                    <span class="avia-arrow"></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item" class="menu-item">
        <a href="about">
            <span class="avia-bullet"></span>
            <span class="avia-menu-text">About</span>
            <span class="avia-menu-fx">
                <span class="avia-arrow-wrap">
                    <span class="avia-arrow"></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item" class="menu-item">
        <a href="contact">
            <span class="avia-bullet"></span>
            <span class="avia-menu-text">Contact</span>
            <span class="avia-menu-fx">
                <span class="avia-arrow-wrap">
                    <span class="avia-arrow"></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
function updateMenu(url) {
        const active = document.querySelector('#menu-item.active');

        if (active !== null) {
            active.classList.remove('active');
        }

        const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#menu-item'));

        links.forEach(function (li) {
            let anchor = li.querySelector("a");
            if (url.indexOf(anchor.href) > -1) {
                li.classList.add("active");
            }
        });
    }
    updateMenu(window.location.href);
```

Comment: I recommend you to use jQuery to make it more dynamic and easy

Comment: It should work, but you could save yourself a query by just adding the remove to the loop `if (url.indexOf(anchor.href) > -1) {li.classList.add("active");} else {li.classList.remove('active');}`

Comment: I could not know because my query information is very little. I will be happy if you help

Comment: Can it be made more dynamic and easier with jquery?

Comment: You don't need jQuery

Comment: where is your active class ?

Comment: I sang jquery for "Amaan warsi". He said you can make it more dynamic and easier with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your function by consolidating your `.add("active")` and `.remove("active")`  calls inside your loop. This saves you a query and avoids unsetting and resetting a class on the same element unnecessarily.

You also don't need the `Array.from()` call.

```
function updateMenu(url) {

  const links = document.querySelectorAll('#menu-item');

  links.forEach(li => {
    let anchor = li.querySelector("a");
    if (url.indexOf(anchor.href) > -1) {
      li.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      li.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
  
  
}

updateMenu(window.location.href);
```